# May be not and may not be

Tags: meaning

I want to say something that means "maybe it is not correct", but by using "may". Should I say

A. "it may be not correct",

or

B. "it may not be correct"?

If one of these is equivalent to "maybe it is not correct", what is the meaning of the other one?

Comment: This is a stylistic answer only, I can't site any sources as far as grammar goes.  "It may be not correct" sounds awkard, and would not be commonly heard from a native English speaker.  Instead, we would likely say "It may be incorrect" or "It may not be correct" or "Maybe it is incorrect."

Comment: Yes lumberjack is correct, "it may be incorrect" is better.

Comment: This is an http://ell.stackexchange.com question, but you definitely want to avoid 'A', for what it's worth.